# cordova emulate android fails with "device is still connecting"

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I'm trying to get a fresh cordova project install working and I can't get it to run in the emulator. When I run `cordova emulate android` it gives me the following error:

```
(node:4822) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: error: device still connecting
```

It does launch the emulator, but nothing happens. I have added this preference in my config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 4):

did you still have this problem? 
i got the same problem, and the problem is that the device is indeed still connecting

fix it right away just by editing `platform/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js` adding `(error.message.indexOf('device still connecting') > -1)` inside if clause on line 344 or inside `module.exports.wait_for_emulator` method so the process won't be terminated and just keep looping until it can start adb.shell.

hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you.  Have you considered submitting a PR to `cordova-android`?  It doesn't appear to be fixed in the latest version: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/7.1.x/bin/templates/cordova/lib/emulator.js#L347

Comment: committed a pull request just now. thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the emulator (manually, or just don't close it from the previous attempt), and the run your command (once again).